# C++ Exception "Skips" Try-Catch Clause in MSVC x64

Tags: c++, windows, exception, visual-c++, 64-bit

I'm writing a program in C++. The program has been working fine for Win32 (x86), and recently I've tried compiling it natively for x64. Of course, stuff didn't work right away.

After debugging the problem, I've managed to reproduce it with this simple code snippet:

```
class MyException { };

int main()
{
    try {
        for (;;) {
            try {
                std::cout << "Throwing" << std::endl;

                throw MyException();

                if (1 == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (const MyException&) {
                std::cout << "Catch 1" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    } catch (const MyException&) {
        std::cout << "Catch 2" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(I'll explain the `if (1==0)` clause soon)

When compiling this code using MSVC for x86 (I've used 2010), the result is as expected:

```
Throwing
Catch 1
Throwing
Catch 1
Throwing
Catch 1
Throwing
Catch 1
...
```

And so on, in an infinite loop.

However, compiling this code for x64 results in:

```
Throwing
Catch 2
Done
```

The exception completely skips the inner catch clause!

This only happens when the `if (1 ==0)` clause exists in my code. When I remove it, the exception is caught in "Catch 1" as expected.

I've tried using other compilers:

- This bug also happens in VS 2012.
- MinGW and MinGW-w64 work as expected.

My question: is this an MSVC bug, or is this some undefined behavior in C++ I'm missing?
If this indeed is an MSVC bug, I'd love to hear some insight on the cause.

Thanks.

Comment: Almost certainly a compiler bug, if you file a bug report at MS Connect (you can link this question) and leave a link here, then I will upvote it.  Would be nice to see what the Microsoft engineers say about it.

Comment: Nice find!  I've just had a go.  Firstly, it crashes the linker on 64-bit release build.  Secondly, I could reproduce it with just `continue`.  The `if` statement around it is unnecessary.  Using VS2012 update 3.

Comment: I've opened a bug report at [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806490/c-exception-skips-try-catch-clause-in-msvc-x64).

Comment: Generates an internal compiler error in VS2013 release build, definitely a compiler bug.

Comment: I've seen this behavior before. It was a long time ago, and I remember it specifically being a compiler bug. There was an explicit reason *and* workaround. However, I'll be damned if I can find it again. It was so long ago. Sorry I can't give you more concrete info, but it is most definitely a bug (and has been encountered before).

Answer (score 1):

This bug may have something to do with compiler optimization -- it's interesting that the linker crashes in your release build (when full optimization would theoretically be turned on).

Does your debug build have optimization completely disabled (/Od)?

Visual Studio Help also contains a statement (under "Optimization Best Practices") discouraging try/catch blocks in 64-bit code.

If you turn off optimization in the release build, the linker doesn't crash.   It also won't crash (but will reproduce the bad behavior) if you remove just the "continue" statement.

```
if (1==0) {
//continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the switch /FAs switch:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX

somewhere in "additional output file" in your "compiler settings". ( make sure all other settings are the sames )

Then, do a diff between both outputs. post the diff here. I'm sure some people will be able to tell you the why and how, and maybe some compiler settings or code workaround.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old known issue, after digging it out this is what we found out some time ago.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19eb8218-0dc4-4e4f-954f-4c4c3b3cd118/why-am-i-not-being-alerted-of-exceptions-from-methods-that-are-run-when-the-application-loads?forum=csharpide

Comment: The link is to a C# issue - the question is about C++