# Exception leaking to system despite try-catch

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got the following code in an application that I've inherited, built against boost 1.48.0 using VS2012

```
bool ConvertToBoolean(const std::string& s)
{
  try
  {
    return boost::lexical_cast<bool>(s);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    if (boost::iequals("true", s.c_str()))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you pass "True" or "False" to this method, `lexical_cast` will throw a bad_lexical_cast exception since it expects "0" or "1" and will evaluate the string comparison instead.

This seems to work fine on my machine, both in and out of the debugger (doesn't it always? :) ), but on one of our customers machines the exception somehow "leaks" and results in the following message when debugging using the dump-file:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD08A06D in application.exe_161117_152748.dmp: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > at memory location 0x00000000002CD9B8.

Stack trace:

```
    KERNELBASE.dll!RaiseException() Unknown
    snowagent.exe!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 154    C++
    application.exe!boost::throw_exception<boost::bad_lexical_cast>(const boost::bad_lexical_cast & e) Line 61  C++
    application.exe!boost::detail::lexical_cast_do_cast<bool,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >::lexical_cast_impl(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & arg) Line 1750  C++
    application.exe!ConvertToBoolean(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & s) Line 111   C++
    application.exe!CScanner::Exec() Line 326   C++
```

What could cause this kind of leakage? It is extremely rare that you get to blame the complier, but as there is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574919/c-exception-skips-try-catch-clause-in-msvc-x64) that has [been fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806490/c-exception-skips-try-catch-clause-in-msvc-x64) in VS2015 I'm tempted to do just that, but then why doesn't it happen on my machine? Could it be because I have VS2015 installed in parallel to VS2012 and therefore have an updated runtime?

<s>Lastly, where in the following disassembly is the exception handling? I'm no expert at ASM, but I expected it to be a bit more ASM for this function. I can't even see the call to `boost::iequals`</s> Update: The exception handling is present, it's just not located in the same assembly block. So the linked compiler issue doesn't seem related to my problem. It is likely something else as @Hans Passant points out in his comment.

```
   107: bool ConvertToBoolean(const std::string& s)
   108: {
000000013FE654F0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
000000013FE654F5  sub         rsp,38h  
000000013FE654F9  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh  
   109:   try
   110:   {
   111:     return boost::lexical_cast<bool>(s);
000000013FE65502  call        boost::detail::lexical_cast_do_cast<bool,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >::lexical_cast_impl (013FD1A0D3h)  
000000013FE65507  jmp         ConvertToBoolean+1Fh (013FE6550Fh)  
   112:   }
   113:   catch (...)
   114:   {
   115:     if (boost::iequals("true", s.c_str()))
   116:     {
   117:       return true;
000000013FE65509  mov         al,1  
000000013FE6550B  jmp         ConvertToBoolean+1Fh (013FE6550Fh)  
   118:     }
   119:   }
   120:   return false;
000000013FE6550D  xor         al,al  
   121: }
000000013FE6550F  add         rsp,38h  
000000013FE65513  ret
```

Update: for completeness, this is the exception block

```
   114:   {
   115:     if (boost::iequals("true", s.c_str()))
00007FF744D9F19B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [s]  
00007FF744D9F19F  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::c_str (07FF74425E8B3h)  
00007FF744D9F1A4  mov         qword ptr [rbp+30h],rax  
00007FF744D9F1A8  lea         rcx,[rbp+28h]  
00007FF744D9F1AC  call        std::locale::locale (07FF744252991h)  
00007FF744D9F1B1  mov         qword ptr [rbp+48h],rax  
00007FF744D9F1B5  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+48h]  
00007FF744D9F1B9  mov         qword ptr [rbp+50h],rax  
00007FF744D9F1BD  mov         r8,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
00007FF744D9F1C1  lea         rdx,[rbp+30h]  
00007FF744D9F1C5  lea         rcx,[CNTServiceCommandLineInfo::`vftable'+11170h (07FF744FBF778h)]  
00007FF744D9F1CC  call        boost::algorithm::iequals<char const [5],char const * __ptr64> (07FF744251596h)  
00007FF744D9F1D1  mov         byte ptr [rbp+20h],al  
00007FF744D9F1D4  lea         rcx,[rbp+28h]  
00007FF744D9F1D8  call        std::locale::~locale (07FF74425D1C0h)  
00007FF744D9F1DD  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+20h]  
00007FF744D9F1E1  test        eax,eax  
00007FF744D9F1E3  je          __catch$?ConvertToBoolean@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z$0+57h (07FF744D9F1F2h)  
   116:     {
   117:       return true;
00007FF744D9F1E5  mov         byte ptr [rbp+38h],1  
00007FF744D9F1E9  lea         rax,[ConvertToBoolean+37h (07FF7444C8FD7h)]  
00007FF744D9F1F0  jmp         __catch$?ConvertToBoolean@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z$0+5Eh (07FF744D9F1F9h)  
   118:     }
   119:   }
00007FF744D9F1F2  lea         rax,[ConvertToBoolean+35h (07FF7444C8FD5h)]  
00007FF744D9F1F9  add         rsp,28h  
00007FF744D9F1FD  pop         rdi  
00007FF744D9F1FE  pop         rbp  
00007FF744D9F1FF  ret
```

Comment: If this exception is thrown while the stack is unwinding from another exception, your `catch` won't be hit. In this case, there should be a call to `std::terminate` in your stack.

Comment: If it only were that simple, Good thought though.

Comment: Blaming the compiler can be a convenient explanation, but these users are not running their own compiler. So that's not it, take a closer look at what you know. Note the " at memory location ..." detail. Only a few exceptions report a memory location. Certainly not bad_lexical_cast. Pretty likely that this started life as an access violation exception and you have code that translates it to a C++ exception, like `_set_se_translator()`.  In other words, it was `throw` that failed.  AVE is usually caused by memory corruption. Could be localized to one machine, if you're lucky

Comment: @Collin Dauphinee: It is perfectly OK to throw new exceptions during stack unwinding of another exception, as long as the new exception is intercepted before it gets a chance to escape into the original unwind path. In this case we are seeing a fully controlled and isolated context - all exceptions are immediately caught by `catch (...)` and not rethrown (assuming `boost::iequals` call does not throw). There no reason for a call to `std::terminate` here.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, In all fairness I wasn't blaming the compiler, I was questioning if the linked issue could be related. And I just found out it is not - the exception handling is present, see update. And yes, you're probably right in that this it is caused by an AVE. I can't find any call to _set_se_translator() though, but that doesn't mean it isn't there in some library.

Comment: @AnT: Unless I'm missing something, the only way an exception can be thrown during stack unwinding is from a destructor, in which case `std::terminate` must be called (as of C++11, I think)

Comment: @Collin Dauphinee: Yes, but the key word here is "from". If some destructor `SomeClass::~SomeClass()` is called during stack unwinding, and a *new* exception is trown somewhere inside `SomeClass::~SomeClass()` and that new exception is allowed to escape **from** `SomeClass::~SomeClass()` call, then `std::terminate` is called. But if all addtional excptions are caught and handled *inside* `SomeClass::~SomeClass()`, without being allowed to escape from `SomeClass::~SomeClass()`, then everything is fine and `std::terminate` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search in the code I found a buffer overrun by no less than 80 bytes.

```
STARTUPINFO startup_info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION process_information;
ZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(startup_info));
ZeroMemory(&process_information, sizeof(startup_info)); <-- wrong size!
```

This code never executed on my machine during testing, hence why the code in the original question worked fine during those tests. An overwritten stack is obviously catastrophic and can cause any number of weird behaviors.